# Java: Generating a random double between the range of a negative double and a positive double

Tags: java, random

I am not very familiar with how to alter the range of both Math.random or a new Random() to generate a double like this. I need to be able to generate a double between -10 and 25 cents (my program is dealing with money; hence why I said cents). And a separate instance is generating a random double between 90 and -75 cents. I saw this when I was searching for my answer:

double result = Math.random() * (upper - lower) + lower;

But when I implemented the idea into my code, the range didn't seem to work when using a range between a positive and a negative number...
I tested it with the upper limit of 0.25 and lower of -0.10, but noticed it printed 0.3567587946356543 at one instance of the test I did. So by this I concluded that I obviously didn't adjust the range correctly..

Please help :(

This is my first time using stackoverflow so please go easy on me, I will elaborate if anything I said didn't make sense..

This is my existing method using this code:

```
public double variation(double price){
    //formula: (Math.random() * range) + min; where range = max - min
    //80% of the time returns amount between -10 & 25 cents
    if(Math.random() > 0.19){ 
        return (Math.random() * 0.35) - 0.10;
    }
    //20% of the time returns amount between -75 & 90 cents
    return (Math.random() * 1.65) - 0.75;
}
```

I know the method takes in a double price that it doesn't use; it's part of the teacher's requirements to take in a double price but to disregard its value. So ignore that please.

Comment: what values you have in `upper` and `lower` - add the lines as code snippet

Comment: when it printed `0.35...` then it comes from the 20% part with range -.75 to 0.90

Comment: Do you want a 2 digit output (such as 0.17) or a longer output (such as 0.11432810481633897)

Comment: @theProgrammer101 personally I would prefer the 2 digit output, but the teacher doesn't care about how "nice" things look.

Comment: As as aside, programs dealing with money should *never* use floating point .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Now you have included all your code in the question, so my answer is changed to:**

When it printed `0.3567587946356543` then it comes from the 20% part with range -.75 to 0.90 when the first `Math.random()` call in `if(Math.random() > 0.19){` becomes false.

**Old answer:**

I think you forgot the minus at the lower value:

```
double upper = 0.25;
double lower = -0.10;
double result = Math.random() * (upper - lower) + lower;
```

Comment: Omg now I feel dumb haha! That makes sense, thank you

Comment: if it solves your problem, then click to the grey checkmark on left side

Answer (score 1):

To generate between `-10` and `25`, try doing :-

```
Random r = new Random();
int d = r.nextInt(35)+1;
d = d - 10;
double result = d/100.0;
```

or a **one liner**

```
double result = ((r.nextInt(35)+1)-10)/100.0;
```

Comment: I need to generate a double, not an int. -10 cents being the lower range of -0.10 and 25 cents being the upper range of 0.25 in this case

Comment: Ah, I see. So just to confirm, r.nextInt() would be randomly choosing an int between 0 and 35?

Comment: @SamanthaHallcox yeah, and we subtract `10` from that, giving you a value between `-10` and `25`.Then we divide by `100`, to give the desired result.

Comment: I definitely am following what you gave me. The one thing I'm stuck on is  the line where you have int d = r.nextInt(35) + 1, if you get 35 as the random int, then after the subsequent code wouldn't I get 0.26? Or is it not inclusive of 35?

Comment: @SamanthaHallcox it is not inclusive of it. Check the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-)

Comment: your input helped me understand the random number generating more, but muescha helped me notice that the only reason I thought I had an "error" is because of the code snippet I added to my question. I gave it a 20% chance to change the range of to -0.75 to 0.9. So it wasn't an error, I just didn't recognize that that's why my program outputted 0.3567587946356543 at one point. So that's my bad

Answer (score 0):

**To get an output with a long decimal:**
it's a little bit rough, but it gets the job done.

```
Random rand = new Random();// creates 'Random' method
int number = rand.nextInt(35)+1;// gets a random integer out of 35
double randDouble = rand.nextDouble();//gets a random double
double finalNumber = ((number + randDouble)-10)/100;//adds the integer and the double,
                                                    //subtracts ten, and divides by 100
System.out.println(finalNumber);// prints the number
```

Here are some examples of the output (copied and pasted exactly).

- 0.22748959958842008
- 0.1963085030978741
- 0.17300671109908058
- -0.002656673961685705
- -0.08854411636457332
- 0.03578255664449403

**To get an output with a two digit output:**

```
Random rand = new Random(); // creates 'Random' method
    float x = rand.nextInt(35)+1; // gets a random integer(0 through 35)
    float y = x - 10; // subtracts that number by ten(making the new range -10 through 25)
    float z = y/100; // puts number in decimal form
```

**NOTICE** this line `int number = rand.nextInt(35)+1`(in the long decimal version). The reason you have to do `+1` at the end is because Java understands 1 as 0. see chart below

```
JAVA   |0 1 2 3 4 5
-------|-----------
HUMANS |1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: this doesn't generate negative values.

Comment: sorry, I accidentally posted it without finishing. let me edit it quickly.

Comment: it now generates negative values. sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your formula is actually correct:

`double result = Math.random() * (upper - lower) + lower;`

You can test it by putting the min and max possible random (which is zero, 1)

```
Random Value | Result
---------------------------
0            | -0.1 (lower)
1            | 0.25
0.5          | 0.075
0.01         | -0.0965
```

Working back to get the Random value for the result to be `0.356758795`, the `Math.random()` must return `1.305025128` which is not gonna be the case. :)

Having said that, Apache Commons3 has this nifty method [`RandomUtils.nextDouble(double startInclusive, double endInclusive);`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomUtils.html) that does it for you.

Comment: But that's the thing, I need the result to be between -0.10 inclusive and 0.25 inclusive. And I'm a beginner with java to be honest so I'm not sure what Apache Commons3 is haha (assuming it has to do with java)

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the code for the Apache Commons3 - it's actually inclusive on both ends. :) Your formula is actually correct - I tried putting min and max values on random :)

Answer (score 0):

I took 400.0 and - 400.0 for example.

`double min = 400.0;
  double max = 2 * min;
  System.out.println(Math.random() * max - min);`

And the output is

`138.0921773815627
212.7567891431654
9.063135840057157
-256.8594518458244
-99.84573995806142
116.53331370219462
33.29613621235126`