# How to generate a random double number in Java? (not necessarily in the range [0,1])

Tags: java, random, double

I want to generate a random `double` number. My approach -

```
Random random = new Random();
double myDouble = random.nextLong() + random.nextDouble();
```

But The result is always a number between -9.99999.... to + 9.99999....

How to get a `double` number in the entire legal `double` range?

The question "[Java: Generating a random double between the range of a negative double and a positive double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43335722/java-generating-a-random-double-between-the-range-of-a-negative-double-and-a-po)"

does not solve my problem as it has lower and upper bound, but I want a result in the entire legal double range

Comment: Duplicate used to close the question changed the more appropriate one

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels mentioned how my question is different

Comment: No, you mentioned about the first Q/A used to close the question. I have since changed it and you should look again

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Ok, this answered my question, thank you

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry about the first duplicate as it was used incorrectly. After I read your question more carefully, I saw immediately that I had to find a better duplicate or re-open the question.